# Combine two PHP objects (classes)

Tags: php, class, object

I'm working on a project that requires a lot of separate objects (classes) to work in unison. I've come up with a solution to my problem, but I just wanted to hear some other perspectives, because I feel like i'm missing something.

So essentially, I have a visitor and a location class, each are initialized and are stored within a variable, such as $visitor and $location; both having data unique to the visitor and location referenced on the page call.

What I want/need to do is essentially make a 'bridge' so I can call a method that will affect both of these objects. For instance, I want to be able to call $bridge->favorite(); and it will both add that favorite reference to the visitor's profile in addition to increasing the number of favorites the location has.

What I have done right now is essentially made a bridge:

```
$bridge = new Bridge($locationclass, $visitorclass);
$bridge->favorite();
```

So it essentially calls another class I have, 'bridge,' with the method favorite, then would use the two classes already set. Which I think is an okay solution, but I feel like i'm missing a better solution.

All input would be extremely helpful, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do this kind of stuff, it means that your application is not well designed.

To answer your example, what you have to do is adding the location to the visitor's favorite places, only.
And if you want to count how many times were a location added to favorites, **count** how many visitors have it in their favorites. Don't store two times the same information.

Comment: Hey Samy, thank you for your time in responding. I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Bridge{

private $classes;

function  construct($classes)
{
 $this->classes  = $classes;
}

function _call($name,$params)
{
  foreach($classes as $class)
  {
    if(method_exists($class,$name)){
     return call_user_method_array($name,$class,$params);
    }
  }else{
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is only a workaround, and use it if you have not other think to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Pethical, thanks for your reply. That is very similar to what I have at current, do you think that is the best solution for the problem?

Comment: If you don't have anothet, then my answere is yes. But you need to redesign your app, if you can, because this is not the best practice.